# How to hide certain schemas from 'Schemas' section in Swagger UI (OpenAPI 3, Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I'm using Springdoc to document my REST API made in Spring Boot.
I need to hide some models/schemas from *Schemas* section in Swagger UI which are used only internally in API, so there is no need to display them in *Schemas* section.

This is one of the models I'm trying to hide:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class EventRole extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String descriptor;
}
```

Superclass of model shown above:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
}
```

Most of annotations in these examples are from JPA or Lombok.
To be clear: `AbstractEntity` is not visible in *Schemas* section – I included it here just in case.

I've tried so far:

- using `@Hidden` annotation on classes I want to hide
- using `@Schema(hidden = true)` on these classes
- adding `SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(EventRole.class, AbstractEntity.class);` to my OpenAPI bean configuration

Also I've tested `@Hidden` on controller methods and it works fine. `@Schema(hidden = true)` hides properly model properties. Unofrtunately, none of them hide whole model. Am I using wrong annotations or there might be other reason why this doesn't work? I'm new to OpenAPI 3.x and Springdoc and it is very likely that I misunderstood something.

Comment: A possible reason could be one of the API is using the model, thus even if you try to hide it, it's still resolved cause the endpoint needs it. Can you check your controller to see if the model is being used or not.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy I'm sure that the model I'm trying to hide isn't used in any controller. I double checked it after reading your comment.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example, maybe on GitHub, BitBucket etc.?

Comment: @Paweł Raglis, you should add reproducible example as proposed by Debargha Roy.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy - thanks for your response. This helped me. In my case the model did appear even if it was hidden because there was a visible Controller that used it

Answer (score 2):

Set value for the property `springdoc.swagger-ui.defaultModelsExpandDepth=-1`
in **application.properties** as described [here](https://springdoc.org/properties.html#_swagger_ui_properties).

Comment: This hides all the schemas and not some specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

It takes me for hours to get the solution

Use `ignoredParameterTypes` in the Docket setting

This one works!

```
Docket()...
.ignoredParameterTypes(ModleName.class)
```

Comment: Isn't this for Springfox? I think the OP is asking for a Springdoc solution.